# Почему jwt необходимо отправлять в заголовке?

Tags: php, jwt

Не понимаю, почему `jwt` необходимо отправлять заголовком:

```
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
header('Authorization: bearer token');
```

Так безопасней? Ведь я могу просто передать это методом `post` с заголовком:

```
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: Можете, но зачем? Помимо POST, существуют ещё GET, PUT, PATCH и DELETE — как там будете передавать, если не в заголовке?

Comment: @andreymal Вы отвечаете вопросом на вопрос. Меня интересует **почему**.  Методами `PUT`, `PATCH` и `DELETE` ещё не пользовался. А в методе `get` так же можно обойтись без заголовка. ответьте пожалуйста по подробнее. Можно и ссылками бросить.

Comment: Окей, переформулирую по-другому: потому что другими способами передавать нет смысла. Помимо POST, существуют ещё GET, PUT, PATH и DELETE — у некоторых из них тела нет и токен туда не поместить. В методе GET тоже нельзя обойтись без заголовка, а помещать токен в адресную строку очевидно небезопасно

Comment: @andreymal Другое дело. Ещё маленький вопрос. Как мне с этим заголовком отработать на сервере? Если функцией `getallheaders();`, то зачем тогда передаём `bearer`?

Comment: По стандарту положено. https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7235 https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6750

Comment: @andreymal Про положено не буду спрашивать, прочитаю в стандарте. Тогда получается я просто откидываю часть строки `bearer ` и декодирую токен?

Comment: Ну как минимум стоит проверить, что bearer действительно bearer, а не [basic](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7617) какой-нибудь. Более конкретно ответить не могу, работать с jwt в php мне не доводилось (только в ruby, да и то с нарушением стандартов)

Comment: @andreymal Спасибо!

Comment: @andreymal Прочитал стандарт. Но bearer используется в стандарте OAuth. Но я то передаю просто `jwt`. Он может использоваться без этого стандарта.

Comment: Ну может и не bearer, но хотя бы какое-то первое слово стоять обязано согласно rfc7235